# Telerik MVC UI - Grid update event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have Ajax editable grid and chart on the same page, I am trying to update the chart when I update or delete a row using the following:

```
.....
    .Events(events => events.Save("onChange"))
.....

function onChange(arg) {

       var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
       chart.dataSource.read();
   }
```

It works but I have to click on the edit button again after clicking on the update.

Would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Please trigger the update button in Javascrript

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same problem, I got the answer from Telerik support: I used events.DataBound instead of events.Save.